# Strategy to identify a good mechanic?

Tags: servicing

I move or travel with some frequency and I run into a lot of difficulty to find a good mechanic in places new for me.

I try to check their service by looking they perform the service (also and mostly because I'm curious), but often they get upset at me for doing that.

Since there are many professional mechanics here, how would you search for a good mechanic, when you can't do the job yourself for some reason?

Comment: This is an impossible question, unless you have a crystal ball.

Comment: If you give some general directions it will help those who can't afford one :-)

Comment: @Moab  I've edited this question to keep it out of the "opinion based" execution squad.  Since you me and Ben are *the ones* (at least that I know of) I still think this can be a decent question, and quite valuable.  I won't blow my own horn, but "How can you identify an honest mechanic?"

Answer (score 3):

The best way is by personal reference from someone you know and trust. Since you know the person and are likely to continue your relationship with them, they really don't have any reason to be less than completely honest with their assessment of the mechanic's services.

Comment: Most people don't know much about cars, and put complete faith in their mechanic, even if they are being taken advantage of, otherwise all the untrustworthy mechanics would go out of business.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question, but from an "honest" mechanic's persepective, I'll say this:

You can have the job done quickly, correctly, or inexpensively.

Pick any two.